# About the computation of the inverse Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

I have several questions about the inverse Laplace transform:

1. If $F(s)$ is a smooth real-valued function vanishing on a large subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. $F(s)$ is supported on a bounded interval), can we compute its inverse Laplace transform?
2. How to compute the inverse Laplace transform of a general function/distribution? (assuming it exists)

I can find  Mellin's inverse formula and Post's inversion formula on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform), but these formulas cannot work in many cases, e.g. when the function cannot be extended analytically to the complex plane. So sometimes they are not very useful in practice. I am wondering if there are any useful criteria and formulas for the computation of the inverse Laplace transform. Thanks.

Comment: Laplace transforms are analytic functions, they cannot be supported on a bounded interval.

Comment: As Michael Renardy noted, inverse Laplace transforms are analytic. As a consequence there don't exist algorithms of the required sort. So you have to make further changed assumptions. For some inverse Laplace transforms there exist accurate algorithms indeed.